# How to get the control under autocomplete if a user inputted the wrong value

Tags: asp.net, jquery, autocomplete

I have a table where each row has a textbox with autocomplete functionality. In the server code it looks like

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="tbNumber" runat="server" onfocus="AttachNumbers(this)" /></td>
```

On the client

```
function AttachNumbers(sender) {
    $(sender).autocomplete({ source: GetNumbers, minLength: 2 });
}

function GetNumbers(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: AJAXSERVICEMETHOD,
        data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "', 'count': 10 }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success:
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                response(data.d);
                //HighlightError(HOW TO GET CONTROL HERE?);
            },
        error:
            function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
    });
}
```

What I need is highlight the textbox if a user didn't choose the number from the list (using the function I have `HighlightError(controlid)`) How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use jQuery.proxy to pass `sender` to `GetNumbers` function as context:

```
function AttachNumbers(sender) {
    var sourceProxy = $.proxy(GetNumbers, sender);
    $(sender).autocomplete({ source: sourceProxy, minLength: 2 });
}

function GetNumbers(request, response) {
    var target = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: AJAXSERVICEMETHOD,
        data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "', 'count': 10 }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success:
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                response(data.d);
                // target refers to sender control
                //HighlightError(HOW TO GET CONTROL HERE?);
            },
        error:
            function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: @Shymep glad to help to schoolmate :)